# Best practice when using fragments in activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment that opens various dialogs and starts async tasks. I use listener pattern so that I get info back from the dialogs or the tasks.

To open the dialog I do the following:

```
public void selectDialog() {
    MyDialog dialog = MyDialog .newInstance();
    dialog.setFragment(this);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "selectDialog");
}
```

And for the task:

```
public void doTask() {
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(getActivity(), this, criteria);
        myTask .execute((Void)null);
}
```

The reason I'm passing the activity and fragment to the task is because the task uses a Sqlite db and the helper class needs a context (ie activity) and also opens an AlertDialog. The fragment is only for casting it as the listener.

With the above implementation, I can only use dialogs and tasks from within fragments now.

Is the above the correct way to open dialogs and start tasks from with fragments? Or should the activity itself be the listener and then pass the info back to the fragment?